# When I generate the rig from my metarig the rig is taller than the metarig

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

When I generate the rig from my metarig the rig is taller than the metarig. Is this normal? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried applying the scale to the rig before generating it?

Comment: You need to always apply the scale of the metarig before generating your rig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You forgot to apply the scale**

It is a very common problem and can be avoided easily. When you created your metarig, you probably scaled it down to align it with your model and you generated your rig and then the generated rig gets the size of the actual unscaled metarig.

To fix this, just delete the generated rig, select the metarig. Press CTRL + A and chose `Apply Scale` then generate the rig.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.